# Angular 2 asterisk template expansion without binding the value

Tags: angular, angular2-template

Is there anyway in Angular 2 to make the template that the asterisk expands into not bind to the input? So for example, the asterisk turns the ngIf into this

```
<template [ngIf]="condition">
  <p>
    Our heroes are true!
  </p>
</template>
```

Is there anyway to have it expand to this:

```
<template ngIf="condition"> // <- this is no longer a binding.
  <p>
    Our heroes are true!
  </p>
</template>
```

I understand this is a bit weird, but what I'm trying to do is have a permissions directive where elements of the ui are removed if the user doesn't have the required role, here's an example, I just want to pass the string 'User' into the directive:

```
<h2 *bydPermission="'User'">You're a user</h2>
```

You'll notice that for now I can work around it by enclosing the value in quotes. I'd rather not do this, though. Removing the asterisk all together won't work also, because I need the TemplateRef inside the directive.

Maybe this is the wrong way to approach this completely. I guess I could inject something into my Components where it has consts of all the Roles.

Comment: Did not understand how data binding prevents removing ui elements...

Comment: I just want to pass the value into the directive, not bind to the component and get the value from there.

If i have [directive]="someField", it's going to try and get the value of someField from the component. If I have directive="someField" it will pass the value "someField" into the directive.

Comment: The removing ui elements is just context for what I am doing.

Comment: Binding variable to component's property is a right way to pass value to it. You will not "get the value from there" unless explicitly define @Output parameter in component and emit the changes back.

Comment: You don't need to bind to a property to pass a value into a directive(or anything). You can do this: directive="someField" and the string 'someField' is passed into the directive. That's what I want to do. But I want to do that with the asterisk template expander. Right now every time it will generate [directive]="someField" and there's no way to change that afaik.

Comment: Ok I understood now. Did you try interpolation with curly brackets? `directive="{{someField}}"`